Meaning of "Who maintains faith to those asleep in the dust"?
This phrase appears in the 2nd bracha of the amida: "Who maintains faith to those asleep in the dust".  What does the phrase mean?  For example, does it refer only to good people.  If so, how good?  If not, what is the logic behind resurrecting evil people?

The main theme of the blessing is Revival of the Dead. Does that help?

I.e. In context, it seems to mean that we don't have to worry that Hashem won't resurrect the dead. Is there a particular interpretation or angle you are asking from?

@RabbiKaii I clarified the question.

I don't understand the clarification. Who said anything about "good" or not "good" people?

@DoubleAA The main theme of the brachah is mituk hadin. The chasimah of the brachah is revival of the dead.

@Yehuda nah, the main theme is God's power as primarily exemplified through his ability to control precipitation and revive the dead

@DoubleAA Even if techiyas hameisim is mentioned several times, your interpretation ignores someich noflim, rofeh cholim, and matir asurim, which are all other examples of mituk hadin.

@Yehuda nah, those are all just examples of powers so they aren't ignored, but most importantly none of those extras is meakeiv.

@DoubleAA. I clarified the question, asking about resurrection of evil people.

Why are you referencing the Amida prayer at all? If you want to ask about who gets resurrected just ask that. This is so confusing.

The statement comes from the words of Avraham, Bereshis 18:27:

וַיַּ֥עַן אַבְרָהָ֖ם וַיֹּאמַ֑ר הִנֵּה־נָ֤א הוֹאַ֙לְתִּי֙ לְדַבֵּ֣ר אֶל־אֲדֹנָ֔י וְאָנֹכִ֖י עָפָ֥ר וָאֵֽפֶר׃
Abraham spoke up, saying, “Here I venture to speak to my lord, I who am but dust and ashes:

The meaning of the verse is explained in the answer here. The dust/soil (עָפָ֥ר) shows richness after one had worked on it and brought forth vegetation. The simple meaning of the phrase is Hashem keeps faith of the people who toil on their product that it will come out well without any thoughts of spirituality. The more midrashic one is in the explanation link and in the comment of Double AA.
Additional meaning, we have a verse in Tehilim 113:7:

He raises the poor from the dust, lifts up the needy from the refuse heap.

That's the faith of those who sleep in the dust.
